# -Dfile.encoding=UTF-16BE crashes JavaFX

Tags: java, linux, javafx, segmentation-fault

When I use the JVM flag `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-16BE` to launch a JavaFX application `libfreetype.so.6` catches a `SIGSEGV`. It only happens in JavaFX applications and if I don't use the flag the application launches fine and I can use UTF-16BE to write files without problem by specifying the charset in my code. This is my crash log https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzW0t4K6XI4gdHhWa0M2YWNtUTQ

Comment: Confirmed.  This happens to me as well, in Debian, kernel 3.16.0-4-amd64, even in a program that does nothing but display an empty TableView in a Scene.  Interestingly, running with `-Dprism.order=sw` does not crash, but does repeatedly generate `java.lang.RuntimeException: Error creating fragment shader` with the first line of the stack trace being `com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Shader.createFromSource`.

Comment: @VGR That's interesting...what make is your graphics card?

Comment: `lspci` shows “Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)” … but I doubt it’s a graphics card issue.  If it were, file.encoding wouldn’t make a difference.

Comment: @VGR Yea but seeing that using software rendering fixes it I was just wondering