# Prevent eclipse from using -Dfile.encoding

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse is launching all of my projects with `-Dfile.encoding` and I can't figure out how to make them launch without it. I've checked the default launch options for my JVM in the eclipse settings but they're empty. The reason I ask is because this flag is causing my JavaFX projects to crash. This is my crash log https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzW0t4K6XI4gdHhWa0M2YWNtUTQ

Comment: What makes you think Eclipse is specifying this? The 'file.encoding' property is set even if you just run a Java program from the command line.

Comment: @greg-449 it's causing my JavaFX applications to crash for some reason and the log says it's being specified.

Comment: @greg-449 I have added my crash logs

Answer (score 0):

Your `file.encoding` is only there as part of the description of your environment. It is very unlikely to have any role in your crash. The JVM is crashing because it has caused a segment violation. In other words, it has accessed memory outside what it was given by the operating system. This reflects a bug in JavaFX and/or the JVM. Maybe you have simply run out of memory and the JVM has been a bit sloppy in handling that situation. (Ideally you should have gotten an OutOfMemoryException.) Or maybe there's a version incompatibility between jars.

Comment: It is the cause of the crash. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37206211/dfile-encoding-utf-16be-crashes-javafx?noredirect=1#comment61970826_37206211 for more details.

Comment: Sorry, I stand corrected. Not that there may not be other ingredients playing a role. And I don't agree with VGR that the graphics card could not be also part of this. There may very well be a code path for handling that encoding that leads to a particular graphics operation and thus the crash.

Comment: that's what I thought but we have different cards. Mine is AMD his is Intel. Then again that doesn't completely rule it out. For now my quick and dirty fix is to setup a run tools configuration that just runs my currently selected resource. It's not perfect but it works.